# Hibernate won't find file although it exists

Tags: java, hibernate

so I have a problem with hibernate, because it somehow won't work anymore.
Somehow it worked for a long time and now it stopped working. So I'm either dumb or blind. or both? :P 
So here is my code:

```
configFile = System.getProperty("user.dir");
configFile += File.separator + "src"
           + File.separator + "main"
           + File.separator + "resources"
           + File.separator;

configFile += "hibernate.cfg.xml";
File file = new File(configFile);
System.out.println(file.exists());
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.configure(configFile);
```

The console even says the file exists:

```
true
/Users/Bernhard1/Dropbox/Ausgaben2/src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml
```

But I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: /Users/Bernhard1/Dropbox/Ausgaben2/src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml not found
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hibernate looks for the file from your classpath then why you are trying to give the exact location of the file? It is not valid

Answer (score 0):

```
Just use:
configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
And give it a try.
Hibernate will pick this file up from resources folder.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I still get the same error

Comment: Can you place this file under src directory and try? Generally, it takes relative path from src directory.

Comment: If you mark your "resources" directory as "Resources Root", then the file will be picked up by just mentioning its name.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Maven project then just try to load the file like this:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

Assuming it is Maven project then the file will be placed in the root of the class path which is `target/classes` directory.

Hibernate looks for the file from root of your classpath, then it should work. Hibernate will not try to look for the file based on absolute path which you are trying, it is not correct.

Comment: I've tried that. I get the same error Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: hibernate.cfg.xml not found

Comment: @user2529173, update your question with what code you have tried. Also you have not confirmed that you are using Maven. My answer is on the assumption that you are using maven and running the program on some IDE like Eclipse